# Logging Level log4j

Tags: java, slf4j

We are using log4j how should I log the following:

```
if (varPerson == null) {
     // should I use DEBUG or WARN or ERROR
}
```

Comment: @lealceldeiro I _doubt it_, seems very weird to catch such exceptions...

Comment: If you have to catch `NullPointerException`s of your code, you should really think about a redesign...

Comment: Do you mean whether to use ERROR or WARN for NPEs? That's a very broad question and might spark debate but I'd use the following rule: if you don't expect an exception to be thrown make it an error. If you expect it to be thrown and can gracefully handle it you might make it a warning or maybe even an info so you are able to look it up in case it might become necessary. As for NPEs: they rarely are expected (you'd normally check things for `null` if you expect something like that) and are also very rarely handled explicitly. I'd catch them in a generic location and log them as errors.

Comment: NPE should **crash**, stop catching them. An application crash is correct and subsequent bugfix release is what you need to do.

Comment: @luk2302 no, you don't always want your application to crash on a npe. Let's assume you build a webservice and miss that some parameter might be missing or have un unexpected value (and that can happen a lot). Would you want it to crash on the first wrong request? Or would you want to return an error, keep the application alive, log the exception and eventually fix it?

Comment: @rlchaps26 `if (varPerson == null) ...` - here you'd check first and thus try to prevent the NPE from happening. What you do in that case depends on your requirements. You could use some defaults, you could return an error, etc. - whether to log it or not would depend on whether it's expected: if you need to know it has happened (so you can fix it or inform your client) you'd want to log it. If you can't prevent it you'd want to handle it differently, e.g. by returning some error to the caller.

Comment: @Thomas theoretically: i want it to crash! Practically: the framework will catch the exception and log it. But from the request handler perspective it crashed, a 500 is the proper response. Don‘t give OP the wrong impression catching an NPE is correct, I highly doubt he is building a web server (framework) from scratch.

Comment: Of course you'd _never_ have a `catch(NullPointerException npe)`. However, you don't always want to return a 500 and might even be able to gracefully handle exceptions. So in some catching even unexpected exceptions (including NPEs as well as other RuntimeExceptions) would make sense so you can still handle the situation without a 500 _and_ log the exception and eventually fix it. Having such requirements doesn't mean you're building a framework from scratch though.

Answer (score 3):

That depends.
If you can mitigate the nullpointer somehow without having bigger problems, you'll simply log it as `warn`.
If you cannot mitigate, you'll log it as `error` and possibly go into a rejecting loop.

Example:

```
if (username==null) {
    LOG.error("Hey. Don't forget your name!");
}
if (password == null) {
    LOG.warn("This guy forgot his password. Mmmh... let's try empty?");
    password = "";
}
```

BTW: Noone should catch a `NullPointerException` anyways, it's a code smell.

If you happen to expect the `NullPointerException`, it's not even optimal to log it on `ERROR` or `WARN` at all. Log it on `DEBUG` and do whatever have to been done with the remainder of your logic.

In case you do a catch-all-throwable-catcher (BIG code smell), you should log that at least on `ERROR` (better `FATAL` if available).

Did I mention that catching `NullPointerException` is a code smell?

Comment: Well, in the end you'd have such a "catch-all-throwable-catcher" to handle anything unexpected (the most low level of those would be the `DefaultUncaugthExceptionHandler`) - so having one as a last resort isn't that big of a code smell. The code smell comes from relying on it for even expected exceptions - or explicitly catching NPEs for that matter ;).

Comment: @Thomas i agree. I would say trying to handle and anticipate unexpected behaviour  is a good thing, no matter how tight you think your code is.

Comment: @Stephan Hogenboom: the question is: How is an `OutOfMemoryError` anticipated or handled properly? Same goes with many other `Throwable` catchers. No `NPE` should be needed to be catched, it should be handled before.

Comment: I edited my question and add some question

Comment: @SirFartALot by rule of thumb the difference between an Error and an Exception is that Exceptions can be handled (sort of, most of the time) Errors 
should not be handled (try to shutdown gracefully, reboot etc). And i never said you should just catch NPE's, i agree you should try to manage them beforehand. But i have witnessed a lot of instances where things went wrong because people thought their code was great and did not manage their exceptions well, because they 'could not happen' etc..

Comment: @Stephan Hogenboom: my rule of thumb: "only catch exceptions, which can be handled properly by the exception block".

Comment: That's a good rule of thumb. What exceptions apply and how they can be handled depends on the application though. If you have some "remote" call (like calling a webservice, displaying a website etc.) you might want to "handle" any exception by at least logging it and returning whatever is appropriate in that situation (like sending an error code, redirecting to an error page etc.).

Comment: NPEs are one example of unexpected exceptions that still might need to be handled gracefully. They normally result from not thinking about everything that could go wrong (who always does this anyways?) and thus will occur in any code base. You might want to log them so you're able to fix them but still not let your application go on - e.g. a webservice call might cause an NPE because a wron parameter has been sent which you didn't expect, you'd then just return an error and let the client try again maybe with different parameters. And eventually you add some codoe to handle that situation.

Comment: @Thomas If a web service throws NullPointerException to indicate a wrong parameter, that web service is broken, and callers need to know about it.  Logging the exception is *not enough.*  Under no circumstances should a web service (or any method, really) act like it worked, when it did not actually carry out the operation it was supposed to perform.

Comment: @VGR you're misunderstanding my point: of course the webservice caller needs to be informed that the call didn't work but that can happen in a number of ways and not always is a http 500 the correct one. Some apis explicitly return a status 2xx along with some json that contains a status and, in case of errors, more information of what went wrong. That's by design and I wouldn't consider that broken.

Comment: @VGR As I've repeated multiple times: NPEs _have_ to be fixed but you don't always want your code to break. As with other runtime exceptions (e.g. temporary db connection issues) you might want to handle them gracefully. I'll repeat: that doesn't mean you'd catch NPEs explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It is on the level you assign to it. For example:

```
logger.error("Oh no error! - {}", e.getClass().getName());
logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
```

Comment: Check `if (e instanceof NullPointerException)` before? OP wants to log NPEs only, I think...

Comment: I assume he is only catching NPE in the block, just showing an example how to log an error and that the level depends on what method he is using.

Comment: how about preventing the null, something like: 

if (varPerson == null) {
     // is the message here WARN or ERROR
}

Comment: Okay I guess you are asking how you SHOULD log it instead of how TO log it? Other answers do a good job explaining what you should do, my answer was according to your question's wording.

Answer (score 0):

Add try catch block around code you run, and catch generic Exception, catching NullPointerException is not best practice.

in catch block you should logger.error("Error while executing code",e)